# Efficient way to implement dynamic routing in Next Js 13

Tags: next.js, routes, seo, next.js13, dynamic-routing

I am new to NextJs and I want to know, what is the efficient way to implement dynamic routing in NextJs 13? Boosting performance and optimising for SEO. I believe dynamic routing might affect the SEO of my website.

Some examples say usePathname, some uses useRouter, and some other examples simply takes params as props in Page component. I'm confused. Provide me an efficient solution for dynamic routing thats better for both SEO and performance. Also explain why is it efficient.